# How to send multiple json objects's data to server in android?

Tags: android, json, http-post, server

How to send multiple json values to server.

```
    public class UserVO {
    private String userId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;   
    private String mobileNumber;
    private String stdCode;
    private String landlineNumber;
    private String countryCode;
    private String stateCode;
    private String zipcode;
    private String status;    
    private LoginVO loginVO;
    private AddressVO addressVO;
    private proofVO proofVO VO;
}
```

i implemented like this.

```
next_Edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new CreateUser().execute();

        }
    });

class CreateUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    int success=0;
    JSONObject json;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ConsentActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Registering New User..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("UserMgmt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        String Firstname = pref.getString("FName", "");
        String Lastname = pref.getString("LName", "");
        String Userid = pref.getString("UserId", "");
        String Password = pref.getString("Password", "");
        String Repassword = pref.getString("RePassword", "");

        String Idproof_typ=pref.getString("IdType","");
        String Idproof_number=pref.getString("IdNumber","");
        String Dob=pref.getString("DOB","");
        String Gender=pref.getString("Gender","");
        String Email=pref.getString("Email","");
        String Mobile_number=pref.getString("Mobile","");
        String Country_code=pref.getString("CountryCode","");
        String Landline=pref.getString("LandLine","");

        String Country=pref.getString("Country","");
        String State=pref.getString("State","");
        String Address=pref.getString("Address","");
        String Pincod=pref.getString("Pincode","");

        boolean Tc_chk_state = pref.getBoolean("ChkBoxTC", true);
        String status_tc_chk=String.valueOf(Tc_chk_state);
        String status_tc=status_tc_chk.substring(0,1);

        boolean Consent_chk_state = pref.getBoolean("ChkBoxConsent", true);
        String status_con_chk=String.valueOf(Tc_chk_state);
        String status_con=status_con_chk.substring(0,1);

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userId", Userid));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstName", Firstname));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lastName", Lastname));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("identityType", Idproof_typ));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("identityNumber", Idproof_number));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dob", Dob));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gender", Gender));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("emailId", Email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobileNumber", Mobile_number));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stdCode", Country_code));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("landlineNumber", Landline));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("countryCode", Country));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stateCode", State));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("zipcode", Pincod));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("status", status_tc));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", Password));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("address", Address));


       /*json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_new_user,
                "POST",params);*/
              //  Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        final  JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        final JSONObject login = new JSONObject();
        final JSONObject address = new JSONObject();
        final JSONObject identity = new JSONObject();
        HttpResponse response;
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://191.121.1.145:8080/medicine/services/users/createUser");
        post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        try {

            Log.e("userId",Userid);
            Log.e("firstName",Firstname);
            Log.e("lastName",Lastname);
            Log.e("emailId",Email);
            Log.e("password",Password);
            Log.e("newPassword",Repassword);
            Log.e("status",status_tc);


            json.put("userId", Userid);
            json.put("firstName", Firstname);
            json.put("lastName", Lastname);
            //json.put("identityType",Idproof_typ);
            //json.put("identityNumber",Idproof_number);
            json.put("dob",Dob);
            json.put("gender",Gender);
            json.put("emailId", Email);
            json.put("mobileNumber",Mobile_number);
            json.put("stdCode",Country_code);
            json.put("landlineNumber",Landline);
            json.put("countryCode",Country);
            json.put("stateCode",State);
            json.put("zipcode",Pincod);
            json.put("status",status_tc);
            //json.put("password",Password);
           // json.put("address",Address);
            jsonArray.put(json);
            try{
                login.put("password",Password);
                jsonArray.put(login);
            }catch(Exception exception){
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }


            try{
                address.put("address",Address);
                jsonArray.put(address);
            }catch(Exception exception){
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }


            try{
                identity.put("identityType",Idproof_typ);
                identity.put("identityNumber",Idproof_number);
                jsonArray.put(identity);
            }catch(Exception exception){
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }

            StringEntity se = new StringEntity( jsonArray.toString());
            se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
            post.setEntity(se);
            response = client.execute(post);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 201){
                Log.e("Responce","OK");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "establishment with server failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // createDialog("Error", "Cannot Estabilish Connection");
        }
        /*try {
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/



        return null;
    }

   protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

   }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();

            /* try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);*/

                if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created a user
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                // closing this screen
                finish();
               } /*else {
                // failed to create user
              //  Log.d("failed to create user", json.toString());

                 }*/
        /*} catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/

    }

}
```

Here upto status is direct values, inside userVO another three VO are there like loginVO,AddressVO,proofVO.

With in these VO classes 5 values are there.

Now how to send these details to server using POST method. I am totally confused.

Can you please give clear solution about this?

Comment: No of these variable are constant or they are changing on run time.

Comment: iam getting those values from edittexts

Comment: can u tell me what is the best way to send... with some sample code

Comment: i post the answer. Check whether it works for you.

Comment: i implemented some code... is it wright

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send data using HTTP post method.

```
 public void postData(){  
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yourdomain.com/post.php");  

    try {
        // Add your data
        List nameValuePairs = new ArrayList(1);

        // Your user variable which are directly send from here 
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data1", "dataValue"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));  

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(20);

        int current = 0;

        while((current = bis.read()) != -1){
            baf.append((byte)current);
        }  

        /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */
        text = new String(baf.toByteArray());
        txtvw.setText(text);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
```

You can find complete tutorial for this on this link https://fahmirahman.wordpress.com/2011/04/26/the-simplest-way-to-post-parameters-between-android-and-php/

Also I recommend you to use ION network library which very easy.

https://github.com/koush/ion

You will find all information you need.

Comment: thanks Code Lord... really i am feeling very happy... for this sample...thanks allot for your help... and already i implemented some code... can u check it? very thanks @Code Lord

Comment: @androidstar dont use both name value pair and json post. Only use one of them. Try to use ion library which very simple. It will reduce your all above code to 10 lines.

Comment: ok @Code Lord... i will delete NameValue pair... and i will try to use json library...

Answer (score 1):

To convert objects into the JSON, you can use [**GSON library**](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

> Gson is a Java library that can be used to convert Java Objects into
>   their JSON representation. It can also be used to convert a JSON
>   string to an equivalent Java object.

**Steps:**

1. Just use the GSON library and got your objects converted into JSON
2. Convert the JSON into the String
3. Post the string using HTTPPost

Answer (score 0):

You have to send it as HTTP. HTTP messages are sent as text. So you need to create a string representation of your JSON object. 
Something like

```
{
  UserVO: {
    userId: "",
    firstName: ""
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with Name Value pair ??? if not try using my following code

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("url");
    List<NameValuePair> value = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    value.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", userId)); //the userid which is inside the  "" is server variable

    //Form as like above for all variable then use below line of code to get response
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(name));

                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        response.getEntity().getContent()));
                String line = "";
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                String result = sb.toString();
```

If you need any help do comment

Comment: already i tried some code...  can you look at that code... yes i implemented name value pair...

Comment: name value pair is enough don't use json.put("userId", Userid);(remove this lines of code and try to execute)

Comment: in my code inside UserVo class another three VO classes are there like addressVO,proofVO, LoginVO so inside these classes sonther 5 values are there... so can i send these values using NameValue pair... if yes... give some code based on my code...